# Magnific Popup get image title of the next slide

Tags: jquery, html, magnific-popup

Is there any way to get image title of the next slide so that we can show it on the next/prev arrows?

Here's the script which i have written in the open callback function:

```
      var num = $('.mfp-container .mfp-content .slide').attr('data-slideid');
      num = parseInt(num);
      console.log('current: '+num);
      var prev = num - 1;
      var next = num + 1;
      console.log('next: '+next);
      console.log('prev: '+prev);

      if(num >= 5) { console.log('next disable'); } else {
          var nextTitle = $('#explore-stay-'+next).text();
          console.log(nextTitle);

          $('.mfp-arrow-right').hover(function(){
          $('.mfp-arrow-right').html(nextTitle+' Next');
            },function(){
                $('.mfp-arrow-right').html('Next');
          });
      }

      if(num <= 0) { console.log('prev disable'); } else {
          var prevTitle = $('#explore-stay-'+prev).text();
          console.log(prevTitle);
          $('.mfp-arrow-left').hover(function(){
          $('.mfp-arrow-left').html(' Previous'+prevTitle);
            },function(){
                $('.mfp-arrow-left').html('Previous');
          });
      }

    }
  }
```

},itemNum);
});

Comment: Have u gone through the documentation? It's hard to read the plugin and give answer, atleast provide some code of what you have done

Comment: @vamsi Updated the post with code, have a look.